# Толщина шрифтов(белых) не браузере в виндовс не та

Tags: css, шрифты, web-fonts

На винде БЕЛЫЕ фонты выглядят толще, чем нужно. На MAC, UBUNTU все в порядке.
Использовал и тайп-кит и локально подключал. 
Пробовал font-smoothing,font-rendering - не помогло

Шрифты - Effra,Objektiv Mk2.
С гугловским фонтом(Oranienbaum) все нормально

(Logotype creation, brands color palette, brandbook and other products to make your brand unique, 
to create single style and elevate the brand value. All that mirroring your brand in style.
And printing materials is one of our specialities as well.)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-разному отрабатывает рендерер шрифтов для некоторых гарнитур. Возможно, не все виды жирности под виндой доступны.  Для Винды попробуйте по юзер-агенту расчехлять что за браузер, вводить специальный css-класс, скажем. в `body` и для него выставлять меньшее значение  font-weight.

Comment: Написал пока в суппорт. Если дельного ничего не ответят буду пробовать этот вариант. Спасибо!